# Javascript - Function on Array confusion

Tags: javascript, function

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]));

// {value:  30, rest:{ value:20, rest:{value: 10, rest: null}}
```

I've looked at this function from eloquent javascript exercise for hours, and can't get it why the result are reversed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the confusion. I used a wrong concept.

Comment: What is the expected output from your `arrayToList()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an output in the loop, than you can see how it works:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = null
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
        console.log(list);
        console.log('\n');
    }

    return list;
}

arrayToList([10, 20, 30]);
```

/* Output

{ value: 10, rest: null }

{ value: 20, rest: { value: 10, rest: null } }

{ value: 30, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 10, rest: null } } }

*/

You have set list = null.

The first time in the loop, list is "**{ value: 10, rest: null }**"

**->** "*null*" nested within.

The second time in the loop, list is "**{ value: 20, rest: { value: 10, rest: null } }**"

**->** "*{ value: 10, rest: null }*" nested within.

For the last time, list is "**{ value: 30, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 10, rest: null } } }**"

**->** "*{ value: 20, rest: { value: 10, rest: null } }*" nested within.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's happening when you are iterating in your `for-loop`:

**First iteration:**
`i = 0`;
`list = {value:10, rest:null}`

**Second iteration:**
`i = 1`;
`list = {value:20, rest:{value:10, rest: null}}`

**Third iteration:** 
`i = 2`;
`list = {value:30,  rest:{value:20, rest:{value:10, rest: null}}}`

On each iteration, you are nesting your `list` object within itself:

`list = {value: array[i], rest: list};`